# How to summarize over multiple columns programatically using ddply?

Tags: r, parsing, eval, plyr

Is it possible to specify which columns to aggregate over with ddply from the arguments of a function, without using eval + parse? Heres what I have so far:

```
x <- c(2,4,3,1,5,7)
y <- c(3,2,6,3,4,6)
group1 <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B")
group2 <- c("X","X","Y","Y","Z","X")

data <- data.frame(group1, group2, x, y)
```

Heres what I want the output to be:

```
aggFunction <- function(dataframe, toAverage, toGroup) {
  out <- ddply(dataframe, toGroup, summarise, 
               x = mean(x),
               y = mean(y))
  return(out)
}

aggFunction(data, c("x", "y"), c("group1", "group2"))

# group1 group2 x   y
# 1      A      X 3 2.5
# 2      A      Y 2 4.5
# 3      B      X 7 6.0
# 4      B      Z 5 4.0
```

Here's my solution using parse(eval):

```
aggFunction <- function(dataframe, toAverage, toGroup) {

  toAverageArgs <- paste(toAverage, " = mean(", toAverage, ")", sep = "", collapse = ", ")
  out <- eval(parse(text = paste("ddply(dataframe, toGroup, here(summarize),", toAverageArgs, ")")))

  return(out)
}
```

This gives me the output that I want.

I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this. I'm aware of using do.call() and get(), but none of my attempts with these have worked.

Heres an attempt;
get(string) didn't work, but here(summarize) let me get the string value. Unfortunately, this means ddply treats them as strings:

```
aggFunction <- function(dataframe, toAverage, toGroup) {

  string <- paste(toAverage, " = mean(", toAverage, ")", sep = "", collapse = ", ")
  out <- ddply(dataframe, toGroup, here(summarise), string)

  return(out)
}

aggFunction(data, c("x", "y"), c("group1", "group2"))

# group1 group2                      ..2
# 1      A      X x = mean(x), y = mean(y)
# 2      A      Y x = mean(x), y = mean(y)
# 3      B      X x = mean(x), y = mean(y)
# 4      B      Z x = mean(x), y = mean(y)
```

Also tried do.call, but they were still treated as strings:

```
aggFunction <- function(dataframe, toAverage, toGroup) {

  string <- paste(toAverage, " = mean(", toAverage, ")", sep = "", collapse = ", ")
  print(string)

  args <- list(dataframe, toGroup, here(summarise), string)
  out <- do.call(ddply, args)

  return(out)
}
aggFunction(data, c("x", "y"), c("group1", "group2"))

# group1 group2 "x = mean(x), y = mean(y)"
# 1      A      X   x = mean(x), y = mean(y)
# 2      A      Y   x = mean(x), y = mean(y)
# 3      B      X   x = mean(x), y = mean(y)
# 4      B      Z   x = mean(x), y = mean(y)
```

Lastly I tried hardcoding in mean(), but then I couldnt set the column name. If I use get(testVar) = mean(get(testVar)) I get unexpected =.

```
aggFunction <- function(dataframe, toAverage, toGroup) {

  testVar <- "x"

  out <- ddply(dataframe, toGroup, here(summarise), 
           get(testVar) = mean(get(testVar))
           ## 
  return(out)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider `dplyr` package - generally it's much faster than `plyr` and also has pretty syntax.

```
library(dplyr)

x <- c(2,4,3,1,5,7)
y <- c(3,2,6,3,4,6)
group1 <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B")
group2 <- c("X","X","Y","Y","Z","X")

aggFunction <- function(dataframe, toAverage, toGroup) {
  dataframe %>%
    group_by_(.dots = toGroup) %>%
    summarise_(.dots = setNames(sprintf("mean(%s)", toAverage), toAverage))
}

data <- data.frame(group1, group2, x, y)
aggFunction(data, c("x", "y"), c("group1", "group2"))
```

It gives:

```
  group1 group2 x   y
1      A      X 3 2.5
2      A      Y 2 4.5
3      B      X 7 6.0
4      B      Z 5 4.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `aggregate` in base R

```
aggFunction <- function(dataframe, toAverage, toGroup) {
  aggregate(dataframe[, toAverage], dataframe[, toGroup], mean)
}

aggFunction(data, c("x", "y"), c("group1", "group2"))

   group1 group2 x   y
1      A      X 3 2.5
2      B      X 7 6.0
3      A      Y 2 4.5
4      B      Z 5 4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a lot easier if you melt the data frame first, do the calculations when in long format, and then cast back.

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
aggFunction <- function(d1, toAverage, toGroup) {
    d2 <- melt(d1, id.vars=toGroup, measure.vars=toAverage)
    d3 <- ddply(d2, ~group1 + group2 + variable, summarize, mean=mean(value))
    dcast(d3, group1 + group2 ~ variable, value.var="mean")
}
aggFunction(data, c("x", "y"), c("group1", "group2"))
##   group1 group2 x   y
## 1      A      X 3 2.5
## 2      A      Y 2 4.5
## 3      B      X 7 6.0
## 4      B      Z 5 4.0
```